# XSLT Extract and conversion of Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<document id="1" class="a">
  <level1 id="2">Hello
    <level2 id="3" class="b">World</level2>
  </level1>     
  <level1 id="4" class="c">foo
     <level2 id="5">
         <level3 id="6" class="d">bar</level3>
     </level2>
  </level1>

</document>
```

How would one write a stylesheet that outputs the following?:

```
<listOfItemsWithClass>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <class>a</class>
  </item>
 
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <class>b</class>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>4</id>
    <class>c</class>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>6</id>
    <class>d</class>
  </item>
</listOfItemsWithClass>
```

Effectively, for each xml element at any level in the source document hierarchy that has any value for the class attribute, create and output an `<item>` element in the transform within a `<listOfItemsWithClass>` parent

Comment: Noted and fixed.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through all nodes you can use `<xsl:for-each select="//*">`. The star preforms wildcard matching. You could build up a list of element using `or` syntax `|`. e.g: `<xsl:for-each select="//document | //level1 | //level2| //level3">`

To filter out nodes that do not include a value in the attribute `class`. Use `[@class!='']`

**For example:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <listOfItemsWithClass>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[@class!='']">
                <item>
                    <id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </id>
                    <class>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
                    </class>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </listOfItemsWithClass>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```